# How to select a complex input field?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to select an element which is actually an input textarea? 
It displays like:

```
<form>
    ...
        <iframe class="redactor_textCtrl redactor_MessageEditor redactor_BbCodeWysiwygEditor redactor_" frameborder="0">

            <html webdriver="true">

            <head>
            <base href="someUrl">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="someUrl">
            </head>

            <body style="overflow-y: hidden; dir="LTR" contenteditable="true">
                  //the input area is here on the page
            <p><br></p>
            </body>

            </html>

       </iframe>

        <textarea name="message_html" id="ctrl_message_html" class="textCtrl MessageEditor BbCodeWysiwygEditor " ... </textarea>
        ...
</form>
```

I was trying to select textarea element but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you are using Java) Actually here you need to switch iframe before finding text editor element as below :-

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.fimdElement(By.cssSelector("iframe.redactor_textCtrl.redactor_MessageEditor.redactor_BbCodeWysiwygEditor redactor_")));

//Now find the text editor 
WebElement texteditor = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));

//Now you can send keys here
texteditor.sendKeys("your value");
```

Comment: No need to switch to iframe as textarea element is outside the iframe tag. iframe ends just before the textarea.

Comment: @Grasshopper yes you are right.. actually it's a text editor which is inside an iframe, and OP want to enter value on texteditor... thanks to point it out...:)

Comment: What do you want actually?? Do you want to locate element with id `ctrl_message_html` or you want to sendKeys on body which is inside an iframe that is texteditor...

Comment: Well. it's a form, so I want to put а message into the form, 
so that to submit the form after that. 
Is it clear? And for some reason a message can not be putted into it.

Comment: Why doesn't work provided code?? Is there any exception or something else??

Comment: Could you share that some reason??